# Trigger insert - prevent inserting duplicate ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I inherited a database from a previous BI Analyst, and the most of them lack PK and FK and contain a large amount of data. I made a trigger to
one of the tables to prevent the insertion of multiple OLD IDs.

My problem is that even if the `OLD_ID` does not exist it still throw the `RAISERROR` message. Can anyone guide me on this?

Also, how can apply this on `UPDATE`?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_DUP_OUTLET 
ON  Outlets
INSTEAD  OF  INSERT
AS

if NOT exists ( 
                select  DISTINCT A.OLD_ID
                from Outlets A
                left join inserted B
                on A.OLD_ID = B.OLD_ID 
                                    )
                begin
                    insert into  RDOutlets 
                    select _ID  ,   OLD_ID  ,BRANCH_NAME    
                    ,ADDRESS,   PROVINCE    ,CITY    
                    CREATE_DATE
                    from inserted
                end
else 

                begin
                    rollback
                    RAISERROR ('Duplicate OLD ID', 16, 1);
                end
go
```

Comment: Replace the LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN to ensure no rows returned if inserted.OLD_ID matches Outlets.OLD_ID

Comment: Done. @JohnD but still not working.

Comment: please share sample data with create table and insert data scripts.

Comment: Hi @JohnD.. It Works! I also disable and enable the trigger :)  Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you just use a unique/primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` then disable and re-enable the trigger.